# How do I make this plugin run only on non-Windows platforms?

Tags: maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  For our project integration testing, we require a virtual frame buffer to be created, using Unix commands.  However, when we run our project on the Windows machines, we don't need this.  We use

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-xvfb</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="Starting xvfb ..." />
                            <exec executable="Xvfb" spawn="true">
                                <arg value=":0.0" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>shutdown-xvfb</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="Ending xvfb ..." />
                            <exec executable="killall">
                                <arg value="Xvfb" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I make the above run when the platform isn't windows and suppress the running of the plugin otherwise?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this with profiles. There is profile activation switch for OS settings. And the plugin is so intelligent, you can use negation.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>!windows</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          ...
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Further information about profiles can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), and about the values you can use [here](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html).

Comment: can you give it a comma seperated value for OS family?

Comment: I want it to execute only on linux