# The parameters 'group' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.5:rpm are missing or invalid

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

When running

```
mvn clean rpm:rpm
```

I get this error : The parameters 'group' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.5:rpm are missing or invalid

My parent pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.brewspberry</groupId>
<artifactId>brewspberry-rpm-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>brewspberry-rpm-parent</name>
<description>brewspberry-rpm-parent</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <rpm.install.basedir>/opt/tomcat</rpm.install.basedir>
    <rpm.install.webapps>${rpm.install.basedir}/webapps</rpm.install.webapps>
    <rpm.install.config>${rpm.install.basedir}/lib</rpm.install.config>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.group>Internet</project.build.group>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>brewspberry-regulator-algo</module>
    <module>brewspberry-api</module>
    <module>brewspberry-core</module>
    <module>brewspberry-jbatches</module>
    <module>brewspberry-webapp</module>
</modules>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rpm-build</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>build-rpm</name>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>rpm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>${rpm.classifier}</classifier>
                                <copyright>Biologeek</copyright>
                                <icon>src/main/resources/img/icon.png</icon>
                                <distribution>Brewspberry</distribution>
                                <targetOS>linux</targetOS>
                                <needarch>noarch</needarch>
                                <group>Internet</group>
                                <packager>${user.name}</packager>
                                <changelogFile>CHANGELOG</changelogFile>
                                <defaultDirmode>540</defaultDirmode>
                                <defaultFilemode>440</defaultFilemode>
                                <defaultUsername>tomcat</defaultUsername>
                                <defaultGroupname>tomcat</defaultGroupname>

                                <properties>
                                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                                    <project.build.group>net.brewspberry</project.build.group>
                                </properties>

                                <requires>
                                    <require>apache-tomcat &gt;= 8.0.24</require>
                                </requires>
                                <mappings>
                                    <mapping>
                                        <directory>${rpm.install.webapps}/brewspberry-api</directory>
                                        <sources>
                                            <source>
                                                <location>./brewspberry-api/target/brewspberry-api/target/brewspberry-api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</location>
                                            </source>
                                        </sources>
                                    </mapping>

                                    <mapping>
                                        <directory>${rpm.install.webapps}/brewspberry-webapp</directory>
                                        <sources>
                                            <source>
                                                <location>./brewspberry-webapp/target/brewspberry-webapp/target/brewspberry-api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</location>
                                            </source>

                                        </sources>
                                    </mapping>
                                </mappings>
                                <postinstallScriptlet>
                                    <scriptFile>
                                        src/main/resources/rpm/postinstall.sh
                                    </scriptFile>
                                    <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
                                </postinstallScriptlet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I tried to modify it by adding or removing project.build.group but still does not work.

I always get this error.

Found several topics about 'sourceEncoding' missing or invalid issue but nothing about 'group' missing or invalid error.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've just got the same error

Comment: No still get the error. Maybe should I change maven-rpm-plugin version and test back. What about you ?

Answer (score 6):

The "**group**" parameter is not the usual "**groupId**" of the POM.
It refers instead to a **group of RPMs** which are usually defined in the file `/usr/share/doc/rpm-$version/GROUPS`.
This is mentioned in the [plugin docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ident-params.html#group).
You need to configure the RPM plugin with the right group; something like this:

---

```
<plugins >
...
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.5</version>
       <configuration>
           <group>Development/Tools</group>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Comment: Hi Nick. To put it simply, my solution is the right one.  The problem is that maven is complaining because a mandatory parameter is missing and the link to the docs I provided tell you exactly how you need to set that parameter. The confusion arises from there being both a *fundamental maven param* called groupId and an unrelated value in the (rarely used) rpms plugin called *group*. Additionally I tried the most voted answer and it did not solve the issue. Mine did.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you specify rpm plugin and its configuration in some one pom file and try to build from parent directory. In this case, maven will run goal `rpm:rpm` on all projects, so rpm plugin will also be applied to all projects which may have no configuration for rpm plugin.

#### Solution:

Move out this plugin to separate child module.

In your case, create e.g. `rpm-package` module with entire profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
     <groupId>net.brewspberry</groupId>
     <!-- I would rename it, parent is not rpm anymore -->
     <artifactId>brewspberry-rpm-parent</artifactId>
     <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <artifactId>rpm-package</artifactId>
   ...
   <!-- move entire block "profiles" here -->
   <profiles>
     <profile>
       <id>rpm-build</id>
       ...
     </profile>
   </profiles>
 </project>
```

And in your parent pom.xml:

```
<modules>
  ...
  <module>rpm-package</module>
</modules>
```

**Do not forget to update mapping's source paths.**

Now you can run:

```
mvn clean package
```

Additionally, see [How do I make this plugin run only on non-Windows platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285199/how-do-i-make-this-plugin-run-only-on-non-windows-platforms) if you also build on Windows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? Should we make plugin def part of profile instead?

Comment: @prash, when profile is activated, plugin wil still be applied to all child modules and you will get the same error. You can move plugin to separate child module and it will do its own single job - build rpm package. Profile can be used, for example, to build rpm only when you specify some options or build on specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add ...

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to activate the profile

```
mvn -P rpm-build rpm:rpm
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the executions tags. Just leave the configuration.