# How to run a plugin only on a particular platform

Tags: linux, maven, plugins, platform

I have a maven plugin that only needs to execute on linux. I found this configuration that seems to work

[How do I make this plugin run only on non-Windows platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285199/how-do-i-make-this-plugin-run-only-on-non-windows-platforms)

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>!mac</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          ...
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

How do I modify it so that it executes only on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OS [`<family>` value](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html) that distinguishes Linux from Unixes, but you can use `<name>` instead.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <name>Linux</name>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          ...
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

FYI, to double-check the value for `<name>` on your Linux machine, execute `java -XshowSettings:properties` and look for the `os.name` property. (On all Linux distributions I have checked, this is just `Linux`.)

Comment: I used the family as Linux and it seems to be working. But thanks for this info